# Exponential Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c

I am working on a project where i have to store user input string characters on the heap and I was concerned about calling memory allocation function too frequently because I was told that system calls can get too costly in terms of speed if they are invoked too many times. 
So I am thinking of allocating memory exponentially. For example, malloc 2 memory locations, then then 4, then, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, and so on...
For me the challenging part of implementing this idea is to come up with the right logic that performs the task with the least complexity. And I came up with the steps below...

1. Malloc x amount of memory (very small chunk 2-4 memory locations).
2. Create a temp int variable (suppose y) to hold the size of allocated, but unused memory chunk.
3. Decrement y every time a character stored in heap.
4. Check the value of y. If it gets below certain number, suppose 2, expand the size of the borrowed memory (exponentially) in heap using realloc.
5. Set the y to new variable that represents the size of new unused, allocated memory in heap.
6. Keep executing the loop above until all the characters read. The number of characters can be from 1 to 10000000.

This is seems like a good start for me, HOWEVER, the problem is that my code gets very complex which I need to avoid at all cost. So I wanted to know if there are any library functions or any other improved logic's that can implement exponential memory allocation in fewer steps... Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't have to be too complicated. Maybe if you posted your code we could help you simplify it. I'd recommend you make a function that handles the logic of checking the value of y and allocating more memory if necessary

Comment: This is basically what stuff like C++ std::vector<> and java ArrayList<> do.

Comment: Often the memory allocated with `malloc` is lazy allocated so I wouldn't worry too much about using too much.

Comment: [Example of Basic Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61507477/3422102) the pointers are handled starting at 2, then doubling each time a `realloc` is required. That is a good balance for growth and size. (there are other approaches, but this provides a simple starting point)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I read through your explanation and it make really good sense to me. The only question I have is about assigning reallocating memory to a temporarily pointer. What if my program is supposed to terminate if OS fails to allocate enough memory? Would having a same pointer in that case be okay? Thank you!

Comment: That's always fine. If you do not want to preserve what you have allocated to that point and will simply exit as a result of the failure -- the temporary pointer is superfluous in that circumstance. As long as you understand why and when to use it -- you are good to make you own call on when it is needed. Good job!