# How to give array as input in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10
#define ROW 10
#define COL 10


char grid[ROW][COL+1] = 
    {
        "--IHH---I-",
        "-H--------",
        "----------",
        "----H-----",
        "----IH----",
        "----H-----",
        "----H-----",
        "-H--------",
        "---------I",
        "-HI--H---I",
    };



void nextState() {

    char tmpGrid[SIZE][SIZE+1];
    int i , j;

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++) {
            tmpGrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++) {
            if(tmpGrid[i][j] == 'I') {
                if(i > 0 && tmpGrid[i-1][j] != '-') {
                    grid[i-1][j] = 'I';
                }
                if(j > 0 && tmpGrid[i][j-1] != '-') {
                    grid[i][j-1] = 'I';
                }
                if(i < (SIZE - 1) && tmpGrid[i+1][j] != '-') {
                    grid[i+1][j] = 'I';
                }
                if(j < (SIZE - 1) && tmpGrid[i][j+1] != '-') {
                    grid[i][j+1] = 'I';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


void printGrid() {
    int i , j;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%c ", grid[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}


int main() {

    int n,sayac;
    sayac = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    while(sayac != n) {

        nextState();
        sayac++;
    }

    printGrid();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to give a string array as input to make it into an algorithm where "H" (healthy) gets infected by "I" (infected) in every iteration  but do not know how to do it. How can I just copy paste an array such as;

```
--IHH---I-
-H--------
----------
----H-----
----IH----
----H-----
----H-----
-H--------
---------I
-HI--H---I
```

Thank you!

Comment: use `nextState(char** grid)`.  Then just write your code as you normally would.  Typically you would need to pass in sizes too, `nextState(char** grid, int x, int y)`

Answer (score 0):

To read the array you need to create a loop and scan the values -

```
int i, j; 
for(i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < COL + 1; j++) {
        char c; 
        scanf("%c",&c);
        if(c != '\n')
            grid[i][j] = c;
        else 
            j--;

     }
}
```

Controlling the loop variable is bad idea. Usually you would just pass the entire array without any new line characters. But since you want that you can use this. I would suggest sending out the entire array without any newlines and removing the else part for new line.

I passed the input as and got the same as output.

```
HHHH
HHHH
HHHH
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get your doubt, but assuming that you want to read a string input from the command line, I would do this:

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv){
        // you have to check if the argument is provided
        if (argc != 2) { printf("arg number not equal 1\n"); exit(1); }
        // code
        // assign the 2nd string pointer of the argument vector to your variable 
        char *string = *argv[1]; 
        // NB: this is unsafe code!! You should always check user input
        // other code
        // printf is your debugging friend
        printf("%s",string);
}
```

With this code, the array is now saved in the `string` variable.

- [Tutorial for argc and argv](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm)
- [Tutorial for pointers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear what you are asking on:

> ```
> How can I just copy paste an array such as ...
> ```

However, if what you are asking is how can I just copy and paste the array as input to my program so it is read into the program, simply reading from `stdin`, as shown in [Saving values to a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61504235/3422102) provides a simple method. (as shown the program will read from a file if the filename is provided as the first argument to the program, or read from `stdin` by default if no filename is provided -- the way many Linux utilities do)

On Linux, then you can simply paste the array into the terminal and then use a *heredoc* to feed the array as input to your program on `stdin`. For example if you compile the code to, e.g., `read_dyn_grid`, the copy/paste using a heredoc would resemble:

```
$ cat << eof | ./read_dyn_grid
> --IHH---I-
> -H--------
> ----------
> ----H-----
> ----IH----
> ----H-----
> ----H-----
> -H--------
> ---------I
> -HI--H---I
> eof
```

The program then reads the array from `stdin` into your program and your program can process the array in any way it needs to.

If you are not on Linux (or Mac), then your options are somewhat limited. The heredoc is not available, so your option is either to pipe multi-line output as input to your program, or simply save your input array into a temporary file to read and either pass the filename or redirect the file on `stdin`.

If this isn't the type of copy/paste of the array you were, then drop a comment and I'm happy to help further.